# Replace largest value in a row with a specific number and replace all other values in that same row based on that largest value using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame consisting of questionnaire data, with each column representing one item on the questionnaire.

The data looks something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(Q1a = c(3, 2, 5, 6, 9), Q1b = c(2, 0, -2, 0, 9), Q2a = c(1, 4, 7, 2, 4), 
             Q2b = c(0, 0, -1, 0, 0), Q3a = c(5, 7, 2, 0, 9), Q3b = c(-2, -2, 3, 6, 9),
             Q4a = c(5, 2, 4, 9, 0), Q4b = c(0, 0, -2, -2, -2))
```

Each questionnaire item has two versions (a, b). I want to select all the items that possess a "b" suffix. For those columns with a "b" suffix, I want to divide the number of cells with a value of -2 against the total number of non-blank and non-NA in that particular column. I want to repeat the above procedure for all columns. I managed to accomplish it with the following code:

```
test <- df %>%
  select(ends_with("b")) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(round(sum(. == -2)/sum(. != "" | . != NA)*100, 
                        digits = 2)))
```

As there is no "group_by" equivalent that I know of that works on columns instead of rows, the same results are repeated in every row of the above output. I have managed to remove the rows with the repeated information with `slice`, using the following code:

```
test <- df %>%
  select(ends_with("b")) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(round(sum(. == -2)/sum(. != "" | . != NA)*100, 
                        digits = 2))) %>%
  slice(1)
```

With the above output, I want to continue my dplyr pipe by replacing the largest value in that row with the value of 1, and all other values as a percentage of the largest value.

What I have is the following:

[image: Before]

The output I want is:

[image: After]

My two questions are:

1). Is there a group_by equivalent that works on columns? If so, I wouldn't have to use `slice` in such a clumsy manner.

2). Could someone help me complete my dplyr pipe to the output that I want? I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Thanks!

Comment: If you store it in some other object say `df1`, you basically need `df1/apply(df1, 1, max)`

Comment: why is your desired output for Q3b 66.67? Should that nog be 40 (ie 2 out of 5 values are -2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, gather your data in long format, then filter NA and 0-values.
Than you can group and summarise.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(ends_with("b")) %>%
  gather() %>%
  filter( !value == 0 | is.na( value ) ) %>%
  group_by( key ) %>%
  summarise( output = round( 100 * length( value[value == -2] ) / n(), digits = 1 ) )

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# key   output
# <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 Q1b     33.3
# 2 Q2b      0  
# 3 Q3b     40  
# 4 Q4b    100
```

Please note that the outcome of Q3b differs from your desired output. Are you sure the desired output is correct?

Comment: Thanks, my desired output is wrong. Give me a moment to change it.

Comment: The lesson here is that dplyr only really shines when the data is tidy, i.e. you can't spread question scores across columns.

Comment: @Wimpel I've made the change. Please update your answer. Thanks and much appreciated!

Comment: @Axeman I agree with you, tidy data is easier to work on. What I encounter at work, unfortunately, is data in wide format across multiple time points.

Comment: That's fine! Just read it in, `gather` immediately and go from there.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks for the tip. Because I have a very wide dataset at times (3000+ columns consisting of questionnaire items at various time points), will gather() be able to accommodate that? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, `gather` and make a data.frame with time, item and score columns.

Answer (score 1):

It's always preferable to work on data in long format. But if `3000+` columns are there in data.frame and OP wants work on data in wide format itself then one solution can be to use `dplyr::summarise_all` instead of `mutate_all` as used by OP:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(ends_with("b")) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(round(sum(. == -2)/sum(!is.na(.))*100, 
                        digits = 2))) %>%
  mutate(maxV = max(.)) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(100*./maxV)) %>%
  select(-maxV)

#     Q1b Q2b   Q3b Q4b
# 1 33.33   0 66.67 100
```

Comment: Thanks, have upvoted your response. However, the correct Q3b response should be 66.66 instead of 40.

Comment: @DTYK Thanks. I have edited the answer. The column name checking with `0` should be just removed. I think all you need is `!is.na(.)` checking.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I realized earlier that both your and @Wimpel response checked for NA and 0. What I needed was to check for blanks ("") and NA instead. In my work, I will check for blanks and NAs instead. Cheers!

Comment: @DTYK On numeric column you dont need to check for `""`. The `""` coerces to `NA` automatically.